# Как добавить несколько шрифтов rails?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

Есть рейлс 4 проект. Мне нужно использовать несколько своих шрифтов, которые находятся у меня в папке.

Знаю, как добавить шрифт, используя css через font-face. Но, насколько я понял, так можно лишь один шрифт, а мне нужно несколько.

Comment: @Денис Сергійович, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: можно и так @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ruslan+Display&subset=cyrillic);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал. Нужно было всего-навсего добавить несколько @font-face в css.